# Linear Regression Doubt

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

I'm studying about Linear Regression and searching about it I found an example that was a graphics that the axis X was the Year and the axis Y was Price, but my doubt is: When we are talking about Year we need to treat that as a Time Series problem, yes? Also, Linear Regression applies just when the variables are continuous, yes?

Comment: When which variables are continuous?

Comment: Statistics is not that simple.  The type of data does not determine what procedure to apply.  The *problem you want to solve* is the principal consideration; everything else flows from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can relate Price to Year using *time series regression*.

A time series regression model for the setting you mention could be formulated like so:

$Price_t = \alpha_0 + \beta_0 Year_t + \epsilon_t$

where $\epsilon_t$ could be temporally correlated and t = 1, ..., n. For example, $\epsilon_t$ could follow an AR(1) process.

In practice, you would need to determine what kind of process best captures the temporal dependence of the model errors.

Usually, with data collected every year, people assume that the underlying process is something like an ARIMA(p,d, q) process and then they determine the values of p, d and q which are best supported by the data.

See here for an example of time series regression with ARIMA errors in R:https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html.

Comment: Amazing! But in this case that I showed, is it wrong? Because when we are treating about ''Year'' and ''Price'' we need to use time series regression instead of linear regression, right?

Comment: Cause and effect nearly always takes place over time even for cross sectional data. Just because it does, does not require time series. In practice time series is used in specific cases, when you have specific issues to deal with. For example when X has an impact on Y at different lags rather than just immediately. As an exception to another point, Linear Probability Models are used with a dependent variable that is not interval. Whether that is legitimate is debated. You need to look carefully at the assumptions of linear regression which are often ignored.

Comment: Victor, the example you gave is consistent with trying to detect whether there is a yearly trend in the values of a continuous variable. In that setting, you could start by fitting a simple linear regression model which assumes independent errors and then check whether the ACF and PACF plots of the residuals exhibit signs of temporal correlation. If they do, you need to upgrade the model to a time series model with ARIMA errors.  There are some issues to consider in the context of time series models - check out “spurious time series regression”.

Comment: Time series regression comes in different flavours, but you have to start somewhere simple when you are just beginning to learn about this subject.

Comment: in all the years I have read time series I have never encountered any I would call easy :)

Comment: I said “simple”, not “easy”. 

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.